# how to translate/convert a binary created in x64 Linux/GNU to a power pc?

Tags: binaryfiles, powerpc

I deployed a matlab script to an executable file which runs on linux platform. 
let's say file :

```
$./run_test.sh
```

As it is created on linux, it cannot be executed on the powerPC CPU. 
Is there any way to translate the binary file to a PPC readable file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing OS & CPU issues: the problem isn't that it was created on linux (there are versions of linux that run on PPC); the problem is that it is for a different CPU (x86, most likely).  And other than running an emulator/simulator for that processor on you PPC box (which, if it works, would likely be quite slow), or getting a hold of the source to re-compile it, I believe you are out of luck.

...unless of course this really is a script, and while executable is not binary, in which case your solution may be as simple as changing the line endings.  This is likely the case if you can open it in a text editor & you can read it (that is, it isn't full of funky symbols).

Comment: What should I exactly do?

Answer (score 0):

Complementing Scott's answer. If you have the source code of the application, you can use [Software Development Toolkit for Linux on Power](https://www-304.ibm.com/webapp/set2/sas/f/lopdiags/sdklop.html) to help you in the migration.

The IBM Software Development Kit for Linux on Power (SDK) is a free, Eclipse-based Integrated Development Environment (IDE). The SDK integrates C/C++ source development with the Advance Toolchain, Post-Link Optimization, and classic Linux performance analysis tools, including Oprofile, Perf and Valgrind.